# Enviar tabla html en Mail::send Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel

¿Es posible enviar una tabla html en un mail de laravel ?

Quiero enviar en el cuerpo del mensaje un texto fijo (que ya logro hacerlo) concantenado con una tabla de html pero al insertar esta tabla en el email no lo envía.

¿Qué puede ser ? o no es posible enviarla ?

Answer (score 1):

Sí, es posible, en la documentación de Laravel hay un ejemplo que muestra la sintaxis:

```
Mail::send('emails.reminder', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
    $m->from('hello@app.com', 'Your Application');

    $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Your Reminder!');
});
```

En el ejemplo anterior, el template es `emails.reminder`, el cual estaría ubicado en `resources/views/emails/reminder.blade.php`. De ahí en adelante puedes incluir lo que desees en el template de blade, funciona igual a los templates de la aplicación web.

Voy a copiar un ejemplo de un template que incluye tablas en una aplicación web en producción con Laravel 5.2:

```
@include('emails.partials.header')
<tr>
    <td style="font-size:40px;padding:20px 0;font-weight:bold;">
        &iexcl;Hola {{ $user->name }}!
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="font-size:16px;padding:0 0 30px 0;color:#666666">
        ---- TEXTO ----
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="font-size:14px;padding:0 0 20px 0;line-height:32px;">
        ---- TEXTO ----
    </td>
</tr>
@include('emails.partials.footer')
```

Y una pequeña parte del include del encabezado, para mostrar que no hay nada en especial en el template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    ....
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="...">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="..." align="left">
            <td align="center" valign="top" style="...">
              .....
```

Solo para referencia, este es el código de la función Mail::send(), en el cual observamos que la vista pasa como primer parámetro:

```
/**
 * Send a new message using a view.
 *
 * @param  string|array  $view
 * @param  array  $data
 * @param  \Closure|string  $callback
 * @return void
 */
public function send($view, array $data, $callback)
{
    // First we need to parse the view, which could either be a string or an array
    // containing both an HTML and plain text versions of the view which should
    // be used when sending an e-mail. We will extract both of them out here.
    list($view, $plain, $raw) = $this->parseView($view);

    $data['message'] = $message = $this->createMessage();

    // Once we have retrieved the view content for the e-mail we will set the body
    // of this message using the HTML type, which will provide a simple wrapper
    // to creating view based emails that are able to receive arrays of data.
    $this->addContent($message, $view, $plain, $raw, $data);

    $this->callMessageBuilder($callback, $message);

    if (isset($this->to['address'])) {
        $message->to($this->to['address'], $this->to['name'], true);
    }

    $message = $message->getSwiftMessage();

    return $this->sendSwiftMessage($message);
}
```